# How to derive a LOCK ID from a user lock handle?

Tags: oracle, locking

I have a lock handle from `dbms_lock.allocate_unique()` but I would like to get the Lock ID from the handle. By ID I mean the value of SYS.DBMS_ALLOCATED_LOCK.LOCKID and V$LOCK.ID1. From what I can see, it seems that the Lock Handle comprises the Lock ID concatenated with another number. However, they are both just numbers, so I don't know whether I can rely on a blunt lock ID = `substr(lock_handle, 10)`.

Why I want this. I would like to be able to check for active User Defined locks in V$LOCK without having to look up the LOCKID in DBMS_ALLOCATED_LOCK by NAME (as NAME is not indexed).

I know why Oracle obfuscate the Lock ID behind the Lock Handle, but in this case I can be quite sure that the Lock ID won't be in a collision.

Comment: What is `SYS.DBMS_ALLOCATE_LOCK`? Such object does not exist. `DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED.NAME` is indexed.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I meant DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED. I'll check about the index. If you're right about NAME being indexed I will need to change my thinking. I might just need a hint to correct the path.